# Bellman-Ford improvement: does it work?

Tags: java, algorithm, bellman-ford

**I'am trying to improve the Bellman-Ford algorithm's performance and I would like to know if the improvement is correct.**

I run the relaxing part not V-1 but V times, and I got a boolean variable involved, which is set `true` if any relax happened during the iteration of the outer loop. If no relax happened at the n. iteration where n <= V, it returns from the loop with the shortest path, but if it relaxes at n = V iteration, that means we have a negative cycle.

I thought it might improve runtime, since sometime we don't have to iterate for V-1 times to find the shortest path, and we can return earlier, and it's also more elegant than checking the cycle with another block of code.

---

```
AdjacencyListALD graph;

int[] distTo;
int[] edgeTo;

public BellmanFord(AdjacencyListALD g)
{
    graph = g;
}

public int findSP(int source, int dest)
{

    // initialization

    distTo = new int[graph.SIZE];
    edgeTo = new int[graph.SIZE];

            for (int i = 0;i<graph.SIZE;i++)
            {
                distTo[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            distTo[source] = 0;

    // relaxing V-1 times + 1 for checking negative cycle = V times

    for(int i = 0;i<(graph.SIZE);i++)
    {
        boolean hasRelaxed=false;

        for(int j = 0;j<graph.SIZE;j++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<graph.sources[j].length;x++)
            {
                int s = j;
                int d = graph.sources[j].get(x).label;
                int w = graph.sources[j].get(x).weight;

                if(distTo[d] > distTo[s]+w)
                {
                    distTo[d] = distTo[s]+w;
                    hasRelaxed = true;                      
                }
            }
        }
        if(!hasRelaxed)
            return distTo[dest];

    }
    System.out.println("Negative cycle detected");
    return -1;


}
```

Comment: I upvoted your question, since I don't know the answer, but your question is how all questions on SO should be.

Comment: The same way you know if any change to code is correct: testing, testing and more testing. Maybe some analysis. But you need to test to make sure that your implementation was what you intended based on your analysis.

Comment: Totally agree with @AndyTurner. Use junit to write some simple tests. What happens if the graph has 0 nodes? 1 node? 2 nodes? 5 nodes?

Comment: See [the section on improvements on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman–Ford_algorithm#Improvements).

Comment: And maybe write some benchmark tests to see if your "improvement" really is an improvement. Although, obligatory caveats about whether you should use micro-benchmarking in Java are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good comments on the need for testing. That's a given. But it doesn't address the underlying question, whether the OP's modifications to Bellman-Ford constitute an improvement *to the algorithm*. And the answer is, yes, this is actually a well-known improvement, as G. Bach pointed out in comments.

The OP's observation is that if, in any relaxation iteration, nothing relaxes, then there will be no changes in subsequent iterations and we can therefore just stop. Absolutely correct. There are no outside influences on the values assigned to the vertices. The only thing updating those values is the relaxation step itself. If it finds *nothing to do* on any iteration there is no way that *something to do* will materialize out of the aether. Ergo we can terminate.

This doesn't affect the complexity of the algorithm, nor does it help with worst case graphs, but it can reduce actual running time in practice.

As for running the relaxation one more time (`|V|` times rather than the usual `|V|-1`), this is just another way of stating the *check for negative cycles* that follows the relaxation step. It's just another way of saying that, when we terminate by running `|V|-1` relaxation iterations, we need to see if any improvement can still be calculated, which reveals a negative cycle.

Bottom line: OP's approach is sound. Now, yes, test the code.